# Sum total of a column with a calculated expression inside Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sum, expression

this is my code with angularjs:

```
<table ng-controller="SimulateController">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td><input ng-model="item.quantity" /></td>
    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
    <td>{{item.quantity * item.price}}</td>
</tr>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

And i need something like this, to obtain the sum of total price column:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>totalsum{{item.quantity * item.price}}</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

How do i get this?, despite of looking for other topics, i couldnt find anything related to calculated expressions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, define a function `getTotal(items)` that computes the total;

```
$scope.getTotal = function (items) {
    // compute and return the total price
}
```

Then in the template:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>{{getTotal(items)}}</th> <!-- or {{getTotal(items) | currency}} -->
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

---

The function computing the total could be implemented as follows:

```
$scope.getTotal = function (items) {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        if (item.quantity) {
            total += item.quantity * item.price;
        }
    };
    return total;
}
```

Ideally you could do that with a `reduce` but that's a out of topic.

Comment: Since `items` are available on scope, you can do without arguments at all. Only `but` is that this function will run every digest, but this is definitivly the simplest solution.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos Im sorry because im newbie with this, what im supposed to put in $scope.getTotal = function (items) { ?? }

Comment: Iterate over the items and adding `item.price * item.quantity` to a `total` variable. I'll edit the answer to show that.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos Thanks a lot , this works for me !! awesome ^^